# Counting bits in a string

Tags: php

I want to count number of bits that a string is comprised of. Pickle is that I don't know what "type of string it is", suppose its a user inputed. Since strlen() returns number of bytes string has, we could simply multiply it by 8 but what if its supplied with a sha256 hash, which is a 256 bit when raw but 64 character long. Applying strlen()*8 logic here will give me 512 bits.

So here is my work around:

```
private function countBits(string $key) : int
{
    $bits  =   (ctype_xdigit($key)) ? 4 : 8;
    return strlen($key)*$bits;
}
```

So is it proper way to count number of bits that string is comprised of? I mean if string is not entirely comprised of hexits then it should always be multiplied with 8, right? or there is still some catch?

Comment: The number of bits in a string is purely based on its length in bytes, not by interpretation of its content.... you're interpreting a set of characters (1-9/a-f) as representing bits, but the string doesn't know or care about that interpretation

Comment: what is `: int` after function ?

Comment: @babuji - return type hint

Comment: If you don't know "what type of string it is" then all bets are off anyway. The string as such contains `strlen * 8` bits, period. However many bits that's equivalent to *when decoded from whatever format it's encoded in* depends on what format it's encoded in, and guessing that is error prone and not an exact science.

Comment: What if the string is base 64 encoded, and just happens to only use characters in the 0-9A-F range by sheer coincidence? You simply can't guess right in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because internal size 256 bits, but block size 512 bits.

simple expirement

```
    <?php

$string = 'test';
$key = hash('sha256',$string);
$value = bin2hex($key);



function str_baseconvert($str, $frombase=10, $tobase=36) {
    $str = trim($str);
    if (intval($frombase) != 10) {
        $len = strlen($str);
        $q = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
            $r = base_convert($str[$i], $frombase, 10);
            $q = bcadd(bcmul($q, $frombase), $r);
        }
    }
    else $q = $str;

    if (intval($tobase) != 10) {
        $s = '';
        while (bccomp($q, '0', 0) > 0) {
            $r = intval(bcmod($q, $tobase));
            $s = base_convert($r, 10, $tobase) . $s;
            $q = bcdiv($q, $tobase, 0);
        }
    }
    else $s = $q;

    return $s;
} 

var_dump(str_baseconvert($key,16,2));
var_dump(strlen($key)*8);
```

first code return return length hesh,
secondary code return length bit in string.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/777ac7c4528357ee21426ad7cab6dcdbdd00edf0
you can see this is example by link.

Comment: This function has to be provided with from/to bases. I was looking to know if its possible to convert user supplied string, which may vary as pointed out be @deceze